# Сбор аналитики с микросервисов

Tags: архитектура, микросервисы, аналитика

Есть больше 10 микросервисов, каждый со своей отдельной БД.
Нужно как-то собирать аналитику по проекту (к примеру кол-во заказов, сколько раз заказы переразмещают, откуда клиенты и т.д.)
Есть ли нормальные инструменты для этого или же правильнее будет создать отдельный свой аналитик сервис и там агрегировать данные со всей системы? если же свой, то каким образом улучшить эффективность?

Comment: Не очень понятна суть, «заказы» звучит как одна сущность, которая должна быть в одной бд, а значит прочитать данные из этой одной бд каким угодно инструментом не должно быть проблем. Вы по какой-то причине размазали заказы по разным бд, или что происходит у вас?

Comment: Очень расплывчатое описание. Если вам нужен аудит (то есть история заказа, кто и когда его менял) - это будет часть вашего микросервиса. Если вам нужна отчетность, то есть срез сегодня, сколько у вас заказов и каких - тут разные опции есть. Если вам надо метрики разные хранить, начиная от каких то простых типа TPS или латенси и заканчивая какими то бизнес метриками и после строить дашборды с графиками - тут полно решений, та же [графана](https://grafana.com/) например как один из вариантов или [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

Comment: Если вам надо строить что то из логов, то как опцию можете обратить вгнимание на [ELK стек](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) / [elastic-stack](https://www.elastic.co/elastic-stack/)